# Checking specific box in a CSV file with something the user enters Python

Tags: python, csv

I would like my program to ask the user what their 'code' is, then check a `CSV` file and locate their code in the file.  My `CSV` file has their code in the first box followed by a number, each code and number is on a different row.

```
import csv
final = 0
count = 0
list = []
choice = str(input("(a) Load a save file or (b) Start afresh"))
if choice == "a" :
    code = str(input("Enter save code"))
    file = csv.reader((open("Load.csv", "r")))
    for row in file:
        list = (row)
        print (list[0])
        if list[0] == code:
            final = count
        count += 1
    print (final)
```

The program should cycle through the rows adding the row to a list, then check the first item of the list to see if it matches with the users code and if they match it should set final to count, which increases by one after every row (It represents the rows position in the CSV, eg. if count is 1 it is searching the first row).

I don't know why it wont change final even when I have the same thing in the csv and the same thing entered into the variable code.

I don't know much about Python and would appreciate help - preferably minor edits and the answer should not be too difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry
I made a really stupid mistake.
I initialised final to zero and when testing I only used the first row forgetting that the index (if that is what you call it) for the first row is actually zero not one.  When I tested for the second row, final would change to one and so on.
I messed up.

Comment: Mistakes happen :) . If you feel this is embarrassing, you can delete your own question. But it's OK if you answer your own question and accept that. Just make sure that your answer meets all standards you would expect from someone else's answer.